# jQuery getting the id of an li

Tags: jquery

I want to write a JQuery code that will give me the id of the li (which contains text "Yes") inside form with `id=f1`

In other words the jquery should give me output `l5`

```
<html>

<body>
    <form  id='f1'>         
    <ul>
        <li id='l1'></li>
        <li id='l2'></li>
        <li id='l3'>
            <ul>
                <li id='l4'></li>
                <li id='l5'>Yes</li>            
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>


<form  id='f2'>         
        <ul>
            <li id='x1'></li>
            <li id='x2'></li>
            <li id='x3'>
                <ul>
                    <li id='x4'></li>
                    <li id='x5'>Yes</li>            
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/GfPS5/)

```
$("#f1 li").filter(function () {
    return $(this).html() == "Yes"
}).attr("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form[id=f1] li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == 'Yes'){
        console.log($(this).attr('id')); // Here is your id 'l5'
    }
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a generic function:

```
$('ul li')click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Or you can be more specific:

```
console.log( $('#f1 li:contains("Yes")').id);
```

This way you can find the id of the li in the f1 form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#f1 li').each(function(){
    if($(this).html().toLowerCase() == "yes") {
      //happy find li with yes

    }   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
jQuery('#f1 li').each(function(indx){
    if(jQuery(this).html().trim()=='Yes'){
        alert(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```